# Map marker as business logo with black border

Tags: android, android-mapview, border

I am creating MapView application in which I have to display business logo whose URL are coming from server, with black border.
I have displayed business logo on MapView but how and where I can draw border around business logo.
I have seen code for drawing circle:

```
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    double latitude = 37.819586;
    double longitude = -122.478532;
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    GeoPoint leftGeo = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1e6),
            (int) (longitude * 1e6));
    Point left = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(leftGeo, left);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00CCFF"));
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(left.x, left.y, 9, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#003399"));
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawCircle(left.x, left.y, 19, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(left.x,left.y,left.x, left.y, paint);

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
}
```

It is just drawing circle. I want to draw border around image in square shape.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the same value for drawing rect i.e. (left, top, right, bottom) it should be

```
drawRect (float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
```

refer [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

and you are passing canvas.drawRect(left.x,left.y,**left.x, left.y**, paint); to both right and bottom